# Удвоение первого элемента списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Как удвоить только первый элемент списка и вывести все оставшиеся элементы без изменений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list1[0]*=2
print(list1)
```